# Python 3.5 printing user inputs

Tags: python-3.5

How do you print input answers such as in :
`name = input("What is your name?")
print("Nice to meet you %s") % (name)`
Thank you if you can answer me.

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("Nice to meet you "+name)
```

Answer (score 0):

With proper string formatting:

```
print("Nice to meet you %s" % name)
```

or

```
print("Nice to meet you {}".format(name))
```

Note the formatting is done inside the print() function